# Python ArcPy: Print the list of the input files that have produced the output and not those with no output

Tags: python, exception, printing, arcpy

I have multiple satellite images and I want to extract the pixel values that should fall into data range I have already selected. However, there are few images with pixel values out of the selected data range, so these images show  `KeyError` while running a  for loop. I used the  `try and except` to prevent the code from stopping at the errors. The output of the code is shown below.

I want to print the file names of those images which have pixel values within the selected data range.

Problem is that the below code prints  all the images/files from the input directory, e.g.,  the file`kisht_asp_int1_clip_121.0.tif` in the output below is out of range  but still gets printed. This really mess up the formatting of the output, which otherwise was in perfect shape to be exported to a csv file for further analysis.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import arcpy
import sys
import os
import numpy as np


def main():
    # folder with input rasters (TIF)
    ws = r'files/files'  ### folder containing Data files

    # definition of the classes
    # classes = "1 3 1;3 15 2;15 50 3;50 200 4;200 400 5;400 1000 6"
    classes = "0 23 1"  ### Class range

    arcpy.env.workspace = ws
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    ws_tmp = 'IN_MEMORY'
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

    # create a list of rasters
    lst_rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

    # loop through the list of rasters
    cnt = 0
    for raster_name in lst_rasters:
        cnt += 1
        # classify the raster
        raster = os.path.join(ws, raster_name)
        out_ras = os.path.join(ws_tmp, "reclass{0}".format(cnt))
        try:
            arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(raster, "VALUE", classes, out_ras, "NODATA")
            
        except KeyError:
  
           continue
    
        # print the resulting statistics
        print(raster_name, end=',') 
        PrintStats(out_ras)

def PrintStats(ras):
    # get the statistics and print them
    fld_val = 'value'
    fld_cnt = 'count'
    flds = (fld_val, fld_cnt)
    curs = arcpy.SearchCursor(ras, flds)
    for row in curs:
        value = row.getValue(fld_val)
        count = row.getValue(fld_cnt)
        area = (count * 30.55555556 * 30.55555556) / 1000000
        print(area)
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
kisht_asp_int1_clip_118.0.tif,0.213804012408
kisht_asp_int1_clip_119.0.tif,0.359452160598
kisht_asp_int1_clip_12.0.tif,0.0298765432186
kisht_asp_int1_clip_120.0.tif,0.086828703729
**kisht_asp_int1_clip_121.0.tif**,kisht_asp_int1_clip_122.0.tif,0.291296296381
kisht_asp_int1_clip_123.0.tif,0.00746913580464
```

Comment: `print(raster_name, end=',')`  is not inside your try/except block, so it will print regardless of exception. Try moving your print statements directly below `arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(raster, "VALUE", classes, out_ras, "NODATA")`.

Comment: I moved the print statements below `arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(raster, "VALUE", classes, out_ras, "NODATA")` but the output is same.